# Store: Trouble with discounted products

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to sell a product at a reduce price in a basic store:product tag. I just need a button that when clicked adds the product to the cart with the reduced price, however, it keeps getting added to the cart at the full $200 price, not the reduce amount of 150.00. Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <input type="hidden" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" value="{min_order_qty}" />
    {modifiers}
        {modifier_options}
            {if option_name == "special"}
                <input type="text" name="{modifier_input_name}" value="{price_mod_val}" />
                <button name="update_cart" class="btn btn-primary">Your Price <span>({price_inc_mod})</span></button>
            {/if}
        {/modifier_options}
    {/modifiers}
{/exp:store:product}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the input value needed to be {option_id}, not {price_mod_val}